# Android Date Picker (Getting current Date)

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Could anyone show me how to get the curent date after clicking a button so that I could do something with it for example if you could get the year you could say somthing like this

```
if year % 4 = 0
{
    it's a leap year
}
```

I also have a few other ideas for it.

Comment: put your code and what you tried?

Comment: That's not the [correct implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) of a (Gregorian, ISO) leap year calculation, just so you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or alternately to above, if an int is more convenient,

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: when I tryed to run it with that the program crashed right away, could you help me this is what I had 
`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

mDateDisplay.setText(year);}`

Comment: what was the exception?  It looks like you didn't initialize mDateDisplay.  in onCreate() you need to add `mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_display)` before you set the text, otherwise the activity has no idea what mDateDisplay is referring to (and replace `R.id.date_display` with the ID of your textview, of course)

Comment: yes sorry I have dont that I just forgot to copy that into it.

Comment: soo is it still failing? if so could you post the exception as an edit?

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
final String TYPE = "YYYY";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(TYPE);
String currentyear = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Alternative try this to get the current year.